# While textview background color in Table row cell is seen, Table row background color is seen too

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

In an Android application, I set up a Table layout with 2 rows and 2 columns
Each cell contains a TextView too

1. I set yellow color as background color of all rows in XML file
2. I set red color as background color of TextView1 in cell1 (row1, column1) and other TextView2 , TextView3, TextView4 in XML file too
3. I set height of Textview1, TextView2,TextView3, TextView4 as following :

```
    TextView1.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    TextView2.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    TextView3.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    TextView4.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

All `layout_height` and `layout_width` for the `TableLayout` and the Rows  and `TextView`'s are set to `wrap_content` too

Now the problem is I see a narrow yellow color above each cell yet
When I increase above mentioned 100 to 105  then the yellow color disappears
So it means height of each row is higher than height of the cell (TextView)

How is that possible?

BTW, when I add **android:layout_gravity="center"**  to textview's, then the yellow color disappears which means height of each row is the same as height of the cell (TextView)

**Update**: when I use EditText instead of TextView there is no problem too (it seems to be a bug!)

Comment: you can try adding textview layout_width and layout_height as match_parent and check.

Comment: checked, not ok yet

Comment: i think TextView1.getLayoutParams().height = 100; is creating some problem.

Comment: yes because when it's removed everything is fine but I can't remove it

Comment: then put a condition if text is present for textview, then make the background of table row as transparent else yellow something like that.